# What's the differences between these two?

Tags: javascript

```js
var func1 = function(){
  // do something
}

var func2 = (function(){
  // do something else
})
```

What's the differences between the func1 and the func2?

Comment: there is no difference

Comment: One does something and the other does something else ? ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Perhaps this question would be better asked like this "What are different ways of declaring a function?"

Comment: (function(){  // do something else}) diffs from function(){  // do something else}, the former one will be executed immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back after five years, I'm sorry to ask this stupid question. Look back, I think he question I really want to ask may be like this:

```js
var func1 = function(){
  // do something
}

var func2 = (function(){
  // do something else
})() // add `()` here
```

Thanks for all the answers from everyone :)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32405189)

Answer (score 2):

They are not different, you're only wrapping the second one in parenthesis, but this will not affect the functionality of the code